# Django handler404 is changing my urls

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have defined my own 404 handler but seems like when I am using it my urls are getting changed.
I have defined the 404 handler in my root urls.py, here is the part of the code

```
def page_not_found(request):
    if request.session.has_key('loggedin'):
        return HttpResponseNotFound(login_404)
    path = request.path
    if path.startswith('/path'):
        return HttpResponseNotFound(non_loign_404)

handler404 = page_not_found
```

Where login_404 and non_login_404 are strings.I rendered and kept them for faster access.

I have different 404 pages as per the context in my application.

Come to my actual problem:

for suppose I have url  **/a/b**
after I enabled the custom 404 handler the url turns to  **/a/a/b**
If I am having **/path/x** it becomes **/path/path/x**

Any thing wrong, please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Until I get encounter the 404 very first time every url if getting resolved properly, but from first 404 page onwards every url is getting resolved as  404.

Comment: What do you mean exactly it "turns to"? When you access `/a/b` (assuming this doesn't exist), the browser redirects you to `/a/a/b` instead of showing your custom 404?

Comment: This is sometimes a problem with how you've configured django in your webserver. How did you set it up?

Comment: My apache configuration is fine. Strongly I see that it is changing the urls when I enabled my custom 404 handler. If  commented out that handlers, actual urls are getting detected.

Comment: How do you have a view in the urls.py? I don't get it